# Tolerance for termination in Nelder-Mead optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to optimize a certain function using the Nelder-Mead method and I need help understanding some of the arguments. I am fairly new to the world of numerical optimizations so, please, forgive my ignorance of what might be obvious to more experienced users. I note that I already looked at [minimize(method=’Nelder-Mead’)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) and at [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) but it was not of as much help as I would have hoped. I am trying to optimize function $f$ under two conditions: (i) I want the optimization to stop once the $f$ value is below a certain value and (ii) once the argument is around the optimal value, I don't want the optimizer to increase the step again (i.e., once it gets below the threshold value and stays below for a couple of iterations, I would like the optimization to terminate). Here is the optimization code I use:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=f, x0=init_pos, method="nelder-mead",
                        options={"initial_simplex": simplex, 
                                 "disp": True, "maxiter" : 25, 
                                 "fatol": 0.50, "adaptive": True})
```

where `f` is my function (*f : RxR -> [0,sqrt(2))*). I understand that `x0=init_pos` are initial values for *f*, `"initial_simplex": simplex` is the initial triangle (in my 2D case), `"maxiter" : 25` means that the optimizer will run up to 25 iterations before terminating.

Here are things I do not understand/I am not sure about:

1. The website [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) says "fatol: Absolute error in func(xopt) between iterations that is acceptable for convergence." Since the optimal value for my function is *f(xopt)=0*, does `"fatol": 0.50` mean that the optimization will terminate once the *f(x)* will have the value of 0.5 or less? If not, how do I modify the condition for termination (in my case, how do I assure that it does stop once *f(x)<=0.5*)? I am ok if the optimizer runs a few more iterations around the region giving *<0.5* but right now it tends to jump out of the near optimal region in a completely random way and I would like to be able to prevent it (if possible).
2. Likewise, as far as I understand, "xatol: Absolute error in xopt between iterations that is acceptable for convergence." means that the optimization will terminate once the difference between the optimal and the present arguments is at most `xatol`. Since in principle I do not know a-priori what the *xopt* is, does it mean in practice that once |x_n - x_(n+1)|, the optimizer will stop? If no, is there a way of adding a constraint to stop the function once it is near the optimal point?

I will appreciate if someone can either answer or give me a better reference than the SciPy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. this condition stops the algorithm as soon as |f(x_n) - f(x_(n+1))| < fatol
2. same : this condition stops the algorithm as soon as |x_n - x_(n+1)| < xatol